# Vue js - async await issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, promise

My Code in Login.Vue is as below

```
methods: {
            async validateLoginBeforeSubmit () {
                this.$validator.validate().then((result) => {
                    if (result) {
                        var data = {
                            email: this.email,
                            password: this.password
                        }
                        var response =  await this.$api('POST', 'login', data);
                    }
                })
            },
        },
```

and this is the prototype function

import Vue from 'vue';

```
Vue.prototype.$api = async() => function(method, url, data){
    if (method == 'POST') {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        this.$http.post(url, data).then((response) => {
          resolve(response);
        }).catch((error) => {
          if (error.response.status == '401') {
            /* Destroy token from local storage and redirect to login page */
          }
          resolve(error.response);
          return false;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

It is throwing below error

```
error  Parsing error: Unexpected reserved word 'await'.
```

Can anyone help me for the same?

Comment: You’re not using await in an async function.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it) in `$api`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't mix and match `async/await` and traditional `then` promise handling as it can cause confusion.

Insted try:

```
async validateLoginBeforeSubmit () {
  var result = await this.$validator.validate()
  if (result) {
    var data = {
      email: this.email,
      password: this.password
    }
    var response = await this.$api('POST', 'login', data);
  }
}
```

Comment: @match-
Your solution works at all, amazing
Now i have one small question
What if i don't want to return anything if catch block execute from the Vue.prototype.$api function and just alert there and return false?